# noData messsage not auto wrapping on window resize

Tags: highcharts

When displaying a long `noData` message on High Chart, the text is not wrapping and is going out of screen/chart.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/9xLyo7xj/

```
lang:{noData:'this is a really long sentence that is supposed to wrap around the window but somehow it is not - I would like it to wrap for easier reading'}
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="add">Add data</button>
<button id="remove">Remove data</button>
<button id="showCustom">Show custom message manually</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  var chart,
    btnRemove = $('#remove'),
    btnAdd = $('#add'),
    btnShow = $('#showCustom');

  btnAdd.click(function() {
    chart.series[0].addPoint(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1)); // Return random integer between 1 and 10.
  });

  btnRemove.click(function() {
    if (chart.series[0].points[0]) {
      chart.series[0].points[0].remove();
    }
  });

  btnShow.click(function() {
    if (!chart.hasData()) {
      chart.hideNoData();
      chart.showNoData("Your custom error message");
    }
  });

  $('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
      text: 'No data in line chart - with custom options'
    },
    series: [{
      type: 'line',
      name: 'Random data',
      data: []
    }],
    lang: {
      noData: "this is a really long sentence that is supposed to wrap around the window but somehow it is not - I would like it to wrap for easier reading"
    },
    noData: {
      style: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: '15px',
        color: '#303030',
        width: 400px
      }
    }
  });

  chart = $('#container').highcharts();
});
```

Comment: If you could set up an example of this in code that would help us in resolving the problem.

Comment: I run this example http://jsfiddle.net/9sL7jxwr/ and rotate my mobile phone, without observation of your issue. Could you update my fiddle with your code?

Comment: The issue is with wrapping of noData message. so if you have a two words noData message, the wrapping would not be required at first place.
If you just put a longer message in lang:noData in same code snippet, you will observe the message is going outside graph and not getting wrapped.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and add a [mcve] - if the external link dies the question is incomplete and unanswerable

Comment: The link is Minimal, Complete and Verifiable. Web is Web because of external links, it is useless to avoid them completely. Stackoverflow can not import the whole internet into it.